# Flutter: How to join two lists

Tags: flutter, dart

```
[
    {
        "user": "90c9d111-4c53-4773-9f13-71a7862d2cac",
        "item": null,
        "drink": 32,
        "quantity": 1,
        "total_amount": "1800.000"
    },
]
```

Here I have my cart in JSON format where `drink` is a foreign key of the drink added, `quantity` is the total number of drinks that have been added by the customer.

Here is a sample JSON of the drinks from an API:

```
[
    {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "4th Street Red",
        "subcategory": 7,
        "price": 1399,
        "country_of_origin": "Kenya",
        "description": "Sweet Red Wine",
        "number_in_stock": 1000,
        "image": "http://xxxx.com/media/media/4th-Street-Red.jpeg",
        "percentage": "4.00",
        "size": 750,
        "is_available": true,
        "date_created": "2020-08-12T12:00:34+0300",
        "slug": "4th-street-red257083",
        "discount_price": null
    },
]
```

I need help on how I will have a list of 3 items (depending on the items in cart) in my flutter application considering the API is already built and can't be changed. I'm trying to create another list depending on the number of items added in the cart.

The final list should contain all the details of the drinks added in the cart together with the quantity and the total amount.

```
{
    "id": 11,
    "name": "4th Street Red",
    "price": 1399,
    "total_amount": "4497.000"
    "quantity": 3,
    "number_in_stock": 1000,
    "image": "http://xxxx.com/media/media/4th-Street-Red.jpeg",
},
```

It should have the given attributes so that I can display the cart easily using a `Listview.builder`.
My question is how do I go about to join the two JSONs to come up with a list which is determined by the number of items in the cart.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: RxDart's switchMap to fetch the cart items, then fetch the individual products before returning the final list..was given this idea,but its kinda difficcult for me to comprehend as am still learning flutter

Comment: It's hard to come up with a solution given how little we know about your code. Anyway, I posted an answer, hope it gives you the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assumptions:**

- There is a list named `drinks` which contains the parsed JSONs for the drinks as `Maps`.
- There is a list named `cart` which contains the parsed JSONs for the orders as `Maps`.

**Solution:**

1. Use `where` to find each drink based on the id provided in `cart`:

```dart
var result = cart.map((e) => drinks.where((d) => d['id'] == e['drink'])).toList();
```

Note: if `drinks` and `cart` include class instances change the comparison accordingly.

2. Store the selected attributes in a list:

```dart
List selectedKeys = ["id", "name", "price", "total_amount", "quantity", "number_in_stock", "image"];
```

3. Use `removeWhere` to remove the extra attributes from the drink JSON.

```dart
result.map((e) => 
  e.first.removeWhere((key, value) => !selectedKeys.contains(key))
).toList();
```

Note: if `drinks` includes class instances, remove `.first`. I used it because I had iterables while testing the code.

Full code:

```dart
List selectedKeys = ["id", "name", "price", "total_amount", "quantity", "number_in_stock", "image"];
var result = cart.map((e) => drinks.where((d) => d['id'] == e['drink'])).toList();
result.map((e) => 
  e.first.removeWhere((key, value) => !selectedKeys.contains(key))
).toList();
```